# How to write a file to a specified folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, path

I'm working on .json to .csv conversion. I am reading a .json file from a folder and splitting the same, and writing the result in the same folder.

What I want is to write those resultant files into a different folder.

```
    new_path = 'C:/Users/toc/Desktop/Python_Codes/Data/Input'
    name = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/toc/Desktop/Python_Codes/Data/JSON_File",
                           filetypes=(("Json File", "*.json"), ("All Files", "*.*")),
                           title="Choose a file."
                           )
    try:
        with open(name,'r', encoding='utf8') as infile:
            o = json.load(infile)
            chunkSize = 1
        for i in range(0, len(o), chunkSize):
            with open(name + '_' + str(i//chunkSize) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(o[i:i+chunkSize], outfile)
    finally:
        print("No file exists")
```

The above code is working file, the only thing I need to know is how do I write those multiple .json files to another folder, which is `new_path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the os.chdir() function to change the current directory: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.chdir

```
    import os
    new_path = 'C:/Users/toc/Desktop/Python_Codes/Data/Input'
    name = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/toc/Desktop/Python_Codes/Data/JSON_File",
                           filetypes=(("Json File", "*.json"), ("All Files", "*.*")),
                           title="Choose a file."
                           )
    try:
        with open(name,'r', encoding='utf8') as infile:
            o = json.load(infile)
            chunkSize = 1
        os.chdir(newpath)
        new_name = os.path.basename(name)
        for i in range(0, len(o), chunkSize):
            with open(new_name + '_' + str(i//chunkSize) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(o[i:i+chunkSize], outfile)
    finally:
        print("No file exists")
```

edit: as ShadowRanger says, you need before to use `os.path.basename` to remove the directory from `name`.

Comment: `name` is most likely going to be a qualified path, so `os.chdir` won't change where you're writing the output unless you strip the directory components from it (e.g. with `os.path.basename`).

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly. You can check below code.
I think you can mention path also with file name while writing. Chane `C:/Path_to_output_directory/` to actual output path.

**Changes:** `with open(  'C:/Path_to_output_directory/' +  name + '_' + str(i // chunkSize) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:`

```
new_path = 'C:/Users/toc/Desktop/Python_Codes/Data/Input'
name = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/toc/Desktop/Python_Codes/Data/JSON_File",
                       filetypes=(("Json File", "*.json"), ("All Files", "*.*")),
                       title="Choose a file."
                       )
try:
    with open(name, 'r', encoding='utf8') as infile:
        o = json.load(infile)
        chunkSize = 1
    for i in range(0, len(o), chunkSize):
        with open(  'C:/Path_to_output_directory/' +  os.path.basename(name) + '_' + str(i // chunkSize) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(o[i:i + chunkSize], outfile)
finally:
    print("No file exists")
```

Comment: `name` is going to be a qualified path. You most likely want to use `os.path.basename` on it when creating the name for the output file.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, yes you are right. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively common manipulation and you can find a lot of ways to do this with a little googling, but to answer your question...

you can pass any qualified file into open so we only need to combine your newpath with a file (as @Tajinder has done in his answer). You can look into libraries to help make this safer and cleaner but I like to use [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html)

so your code might look something like this:

```
    import os
    new_path = 'C:/Users/toc/Desktop/Python_Codes/Data/Input'
    name = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/toc/Desktop/Python_Codes/Data/JSON_File",
                           filetypes=(("Json File", "*.json"), ("All Files", "*.*")),
                           title="Choose a file."
                           )
    try:
        with open(name,'r', encoding='utf8') as infile:
            o = json.load(infile)
            chunkSize = 1
        for i in range(0, len(o), chunkSize):
            with open(os.path.join(newpath, os.path.basename(name).rsplit('.',1)[0] + '_' + str(i//chunkSize) + '.json'), 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(o[i:i+chunkSize], outfile)
    finally:
        print("No file exists")
```

Edited to do a quick fix (read not the cleanest way) to remove the directory portion and extension from name which @ShadowRanger rightly pointed out is likely to be a qualified path all on its own.